# how to create SOAP/webservice in dot net core 2 web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-services, wcf, soap

We have in my company very many websites running at customers servers and they all report back to one license-website via old school webservice. A webservice with old *.asmx files. This license site is now to be replaced by a core2 web app. So we need an identical webservice there too.

So, how do I create the webservice/SOAP service in a core2 app?

Similar question have been asked before but the latest I found was more than a year ago and I guess status have changed to something good now. Status in summer 2016: "Microsoft currently does not plan to ship a SOAP server side framework for .NET Core. Neither the WCF ServiceHost nor ASMX are available. Too early to tell, which of the non-Microsoft stacks will jump in and be the dominant player"

Best bet so far?
http://docs.servicestack.net/soap-support
https://stackify.com/soap-net-core/